# Match on a URL with mod_rewrite only with a very specific pattern

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite, expressionengine

I have a small problem to solve. I have two applications running side by side (CodeIgniter and ExpressionEngine) and I need to route specific URL patterns to CI and everything else to EE. So far this is mostly working but there's one small detail. Here's the code I currently have:

```
# Rewrite requests for anything that's not a CI controller or physical file/folder to ExpressionEngine
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond $1 !(admin|cron|fst_reporting|playcatch|ppv|purchase|reporting|xml) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]

# Route everything else to CodeIgniter
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /app/index.php/$1 [L]
```

However I also want to push any requests for:

```
/training
/training/
/training/programme/something
/training/programme/something/
```

to EE in the first conditional block and then force requests for one specific URL pattern

```
/training/something
```

to the CI application (as see in the 2nd conditional block).

The problem I have is trying to blend the above requirements into my existing conditional statement, ideally I want to say "Anything which is NOT equal to my code igniter controllers OR is equal to /training or /training/programme/something". Meanwhile I still need to be able to route requests for /training/something (where something is a random string of characters) to the CI app.

Any ideas? :)

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps something like:

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/training(/)?(/programme/something)?(/)? [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond $1 !(admin|cron|fst_reporting|playcatch|ppv|purchase|reporting|xml) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

hope that helps.

Comment: Hi Rob, thanks for this.., the (/programme/something) part needs to match on a pattern such as "/programme/MTMwfG5pbmVmb3Vy" but at the same time must not match a URL such as "/programme/fire-safety/training". This is what really has me stuck. :/

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response!  Try this on for size:  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/training(/)?(/programme/)?(?!.*training$)/?   This should match anything that starts with training, could have programme, and then has whatever, as long as it looks ahead and doesn't see "training".  This will likely only work if you're running Apache 2.x, because I think 1.x doesn't support look-ahead regular expressions?  I hope it works for you.